# SQL - get values from rows

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
id    date      name     id2
1     1/1/2017  demi
2     1/2/2017  demi
3     1/3/2017  demi
```

I would like the id2 column to display id based on most recent date. The output should be:

```
id    date      name     id2
1     1/1/2017  demi     2
2     1/2/2017  demi     3
3     1/3/2017  demi
```

Any help would by appreciated.

Comment: I don't get this, how do you find the id2 value 2 for the row with id = 1?

Comment: Can you explain your requirements better? This doesn't make sense. Shouldn't both values for id2 be 3 for id 1 and 2? That is the max date for 'demi'

Comment: Why is id2 set to 2 on row 1?  the most recent date in your table is 1/3/2017, which would mean id2 should be set to 3 for all rows.  Do you mean that you want the date of the next row?

Comment: I didn't do a good job on describing the issue. Sorry about that. 
I do have another column called Entid which is the unique identifier.
Pretty much, I would like the id2 to display the id of the row based on the next closest date after.

Comment: Wouldn't the most recent date in this case be 1/3/2017? In which case it wouldn't show anything for id2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MS SQL you can use next query:

> ```
> create table mytable (id int, [date] date, name varchar(100), id2 int);
> insert into mytable values
> (1,     '20170101',  'demi', null),
> (2,     '20170201',  'demi', null),
> (3,     '20170301',  'demi', null);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT id, [date], name, 
>        (SELECT TOP 1 id
>         FROM   mytable
>         WHERE  [date] > t1.[date]
>         ORDER BY id, [date] ASC) id2
> FROM   mytable t1
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | date                | name |  id2
> -: | :------------------ | :--- | ---:
>  1 | 01/01/2017 00:00:00 | demi |    2
>  2 | 01/02/2017 00:00:00 | demi |    3
>  3 | 01/03/2017 00:00:00 | demi | null
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d37761c0fe1b81ae8bdbb583627bcd1d)*